# res.data won't save to state correctly

Tags: mongodb, axios

I have a MERN app which pulls data from a collection in MongoDB to render a timer component in the DOM. Currently in my collection, I have three timers titled `first timer`, `another timer` and `even another`. When I make a get request and run `console.log(res.data)`, I see all the timers and their relevant data logged to the console. However, when I try to set state of timers using the useState hook, only the last timer is saved to state. Here is the code of my component:

```html
function Wrapper() {
  const [timers, setTimers] = useState([]);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:3001/')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        res.data.map((timer) => {
          let newTimer = (
            <Timer title={timer.title} id={timer._id} time={timer.time} />
          );
          let allTimers = timers.slice();
          allTimers.push(newTimer);
          setTimers(allTimers);
          console.log(allTimers);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here I am making my get request and mapping through the res.data to create a new timer component for each iteration. Then, I make a copy of `timers` (since state is immutable), push my new timer to `allTimers` variable and finally run `setTimers(allTimers)`. Here is what React renders:

[image]

I expect `allTimers` to contain one, two and then all three of the timers in my database when logged to the consol on line 17. However, only the most recent timer shows up so it seems like I am setting state incorrectly but I'm not sure how. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set `useEffect` to Only runs on initial render, it always refers to the initial state of `timers`, which is an empty array, and even as you try to update it with `useState` but on the next loop it still refers to the empty array. The only update to have real effect is the last one, pushing the third timer into the empty array.
You can move your entire `map` loop to the return statement of the functional component to render an element for each timer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I was doing something goofy. Do you think it would be best practice to make a function that gets all the timers and then call that in `useEffect` or just to write the get request in `useEffect`?

Comment: Technically it is the same, making a separate function makes it easier to read and maintain.